# Creating a local vector in a parallel PETSC program

Tags: petsc

In one of my PETSc programs, I need a processor to access values from another processor.

So in the PETSc FAQ's this issue has been briefly addressed [here](http://www.mcs.anl.gov/petsc/documentation/faq.html#mpi-vec-access). 
To create a local vector, I tried this

```
Vec local;
ierr = VecCreateSeq(PETSC_COMM_WORLD,10,&local);CHKERRQ(ierr);
```

where 10 is the size of the local vector I wish to create. 
But running with 2 processors gives me an error

```
[0]PETSC ERROR: --------------------- Error Message ------------------------------------
[0]PETSC ERROR: Invalid argument!
[0]PETSC ERROR: Cannot create VECSEQ on more than one process!
[0]PETSC ERROR: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

So to be more precise,
I would like to write a toy code where I want to add all elements from a big vector `v` which is spread across n processors.

I would like to do this 
by gathering all elements from `v` onto a vector local to Process 0 
and add them all up.

Also more generally how would Process 0 get elements from any specific processor
say processor `i`

Answer (score 2):

`PETSC_COMM_WORLD` is a *global* communicator.  Use `PETSC_COMM_SELF` to create a sequential object.

Use [VecScatterCreateToZero](http://www.mcs.anl.gov/petsc/petsc-current/docs/manualpages/Vec/VecScatterCreateToZero.html) for gathering to rank 0. (Obviously this is not memory scalable, so try not to do this in a real application.)

Use [VecScatter](http://www.mcs.anl.gov/petsc/petsc-current/docs/manualpages/Vec/VecScatter.html) for arbitrary (often sparse) collective vector distributions.